# How to create a WebXR-AR app made by Cordova( IOS and Android)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, augmented-reality, webxr

For the installation of the application, I set up xcode for ios and android studio for android. Unfortunately, augmented reality cannot appear in the application, i guess main issue is coming from this part of code:

```
    if ( 'xr' in navigator ) {

    navigator.xr.isSessionSupported( 'immersive-ar' ).then( ( supported ) => {

        if (supported){
            const collection = document.getElementsByClassName("ar-button");
            [...collection].forEach( el => {
                el.style.display = 'block';
            });
        }
        
    } );
    
} 
else{
      alert("not supported");
    }
```

When I try to start the session with the code I wrote above. It's not working because i believe xr not supported.I tried cordova-webxr-plugin as well. However, it didn't work.

Does anyone have any idea about my problem or any related suggestion to that?